# Consuming a deserialised Exchange 2013 PSSession in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-management-shell

I have created a `New-PSSession` to a `ConnectionUri` for an Exchange 2013 server, but see that the type of the session is `Deserialised`. This deserialised session cannot be consumed by `Invoke-Command`, `Enter-PSSession` or `Import-PSSession`.

How do I consume a `Deserialised` `PSSession`? My goal is to view the `Get-Queue` of the exchange server.

The below code:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<fqdn of exchange server>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $UserCredential
#Cannot convert session to non-Deserialized type
Enter-PSSession -session $Session
#Cannot convert session to non-Deserialized type
Import-PSSession -session $Session
#Cannot convert session to non-Deserialized type
icm -session $Session -ScriptBlock {Get-queue}
```

Throws the following error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Session'. Cannot convert the "[PSSession]Session6" value of type "Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession" to type "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession".
```

Comment: if you use https:// instead of http:// is that then working for you?

Comment: After restarting PowerShell, I got a normal (hydrated?) session object. Not sure what caused this.

Comment: Super late on this, but I got it working by just starting a new powershell instance too. Just wanted to confirm this for people popping in on this thread in the future.